# How to lower Gluster FS down peer timeout / reduce down peer impact?

Tags: high-availability, glusterfs

The setting:
Two fresh CentOS 6.5 server with latest updates.  Both have a fresh install of Gluster 3.5.2.

What I did ( from the perspective of server 2, shared1 and shared2 are logical volumes ) :

```
wget -P /etc/yum.repos.d http://download.gluster.org/pub/gluster/glusterfs/LATEST/CentOS/glusterfs-epel.repo
yum -y install glusterfs glusterfs-fuse glusterfs-server -y
/etc/init.d/glusterd start
chkconfig --level 345 glusterd on

echo "1.2.3.4 server1" >> /etc/hosts
echo "4.3.2.1 server2" >> /etc/hosts

gluster peer probe server1
gluster volume create shared replica 2 transport tcp server2:/shared2 server1:/shared1 force
gluster volume start shared

mount.glusterfs server2:/shared /mnt/shared

gluster peer status
```

This worked perfectly, and I have a nice shared filesystem on /mnt/shared on both servers.  The command set was executed on each server respectively, and modified to match that server's perspective.

The testing:

If I press the reset button on server1, I have a horrible ~45 second delay in using or accessing files on /mnt/shared

I did search for a solution on google, glusterfs admin guide, and on serverfault, but no one seems to have this issue.

Any advice on how to lower the timeouts, or ignore a down peer temporarily?  A read-only state during failover is fine as long as there's no delays.  Or, just tell me what I did wrong, or did not do.

Thanks,

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You may be suffering from the client ping timeout setting as its default is 42 seconds.
Run the following to check:

`gluster volume info shared`

The parameter you are looking for is "network.ping-timeout". You can change this by running

`gluster volume set shared network.ping-timeout "new timeout value"`

See if that reduces the recovery period.

Comment: This was exactly my issue.  Thanks for pointing out this not-so-easy to find gem.

Comment: The 42 seconds default can be found at https://gluster.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Administrator%20Guide/Managing%20Volumes/